# SimpleXML leer nombre del nodo

Tags: php, xml, simplexml, nodos

pues vuelvo con mis problemas para leer XML.

Pongamos este ejemplo de XML

```
<TED>
 <FORM_SECTION>
  <SECC_1>
    ....
  <SECC_2>
    ....
  <SECC_3>
    ....
```

Con simpleXML para acceder a las SECC_X sería tan simple como

```
$xml->FORM_SECCTION->SECC_X->xxxxx
```

Pero el problema que tengo es que SECC_N es un número no siempre determinado, ni con números correlativos, y ni siquiera con el mismo formato, aquí tenemos SECC_X pero en otros casos puede llamarse CASO_X por ejemplo, o MODELO_X o cualquier otra cosa, por lo que necesito, de alguna manera poder "saber" el nombre de los nodos.

Yo he probado algo como esto

```
$secciones = $xml->FORM_SECTION;

  foreach ($secciones as $seccion => $name) {
    echo "seccion : $seccion - name: $name<br>";
  }
```

Pero $name no me dice el nombre de los nodos hijos de FORM_SECTION y $seccion devuelve literalmente **FORM_SECCTION**

Estoy segura de que es mucho más fácil de lo que yo estoy pensando pero... no acierto

Comment: ¿No te sirve **[`getName()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/simplexmlelement.getname.php)**? Sería algo así más o menos: `foreach ($secciones as $seccion) {
    echo "seccion : $seccion->getName()<br>";
  }`

Comment: Si dejo el código así: foreach ($secciones as $seccion => $name) {
    echo "seccion : $seccion - name: ".$name->getName()."<br>"; ambas variables devuelven FORM_SECTION, mientras que si elimino $name y en el echo pongo $seccion->getName(); me devuelve también FORM_SECTION :(

Comment: ¿No hay acaso confusión en tu código? Prueba así: `foreach ($secciones->children() as $seccion) { echo $seccion->getName()."<br>"; }`  o bien así, como te dije en el primer comentario: `foreach ($secciones as $seccion) { echo "seccion : $seccion->getName()<br>"; }` Si no funciona, haz un `var_dump($seccion);` dentro del bucle para ver lo que hay dentro realmente.

Comment: foreach ($secciones->children() as $seccion) { echo $seccion->getName()."<br>"; } esta sí que ha servido !!! Nota mental: debería leerme mejor la documentación de simpleXML, porque esa función children() no la había visto y es de lo más lógica y coherente :( Pon respuesta y te la marco como buena ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar **[`getName()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/simplexmlelement.getname.php)**, combinado con `children()`.

> El método getName retorna como string el nombre de la etiqueta XML
>   referenciada por el objeto SimpleXMLElement.

Por ejemplo:

```
foreach ($secciones->children() as $seccion) { 
    echo $seccion->getName()."<br>"; 
}
```

Comment: Mil gracias !!! Al final sí que era más simple de lo que yo pensaba, tiendo a complicar mucho las cosas:_

Comment: @VeraCanet se llama `SimpleXML`, no `ComplicatedXML`, así que no compliques. Me alegro de que te haya servido. Saludos.